# Refresh page or Redirect page after some time to new URL in Loop

Tags: php, javascript

i want to refresh page or redirect page after 4 mints to new url every time it refresh or redirect 
**Example some thing like this**

```
$i=1
while($i = 100){
 //** Now URL redirect here 
$url="u_pc_change.php?id=$i";
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url='.$url.'">';
$i++;
 }
```

some code which wait here for 4mints and redirect or refresh the page to new url like

```
u_pc_change.php?id=1
u_pc_change.php?id=2
u_pc_change.php?id=3
```

Above code will not work because it do fast loop and nothing will wait for 4 mints ... i need a way to wait 4 mints before 2nd loop happen .... for refresh or redirect.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @PankajKhairnar I want to redirect or refresh page after 4 mint but to new URL every time.

Comment: @Harinder the code you provided is pretty useless, that only lasts 2s ..

Comment: @dbf i know that is the problem i am facing .... that is why i have ask question

Comment: @Harinder why don't you just use javascript to redirect the page?

Comment: have you looked at javascript timing functions?? `setTimeout` `setInterval`?

Comment: @dm03514 `setInterval` is pretty useless if the page is being refreshed ..

Comment: i think you misunderstand that php is executed on the server entirely and then the computed response is sent to the client. No more php code will be executed after the client sees the page, unless he reloades the page, or an ajax (or any other) request is made. If you wait in php code, the client will not see his page until the code finishes computing.

Comment: @cppanda i no that i am ready to do this in any thing, like Ajax will also do ... just want to run a script on targeted page with $_GET[$id] to change the parameter to run script . thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait 4 minutes, you can use JS like this:

```
<script>setTimeout(function() { document.location='your_desired_location';},1000 * 60 * 4);</script>
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to show something different every 4 minutes regardless if user refreshed page, left and returned, or just stayed on page for 4 minutes.

You can save user refresh time and check it next time.

```
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['lastRefresh']) ) $_SESSION['lastRefresh'] = time(); //User is here for first time
else {        
    if( time() - $_SESSION['lastRefresh']  > 60 * 4 )//Show something else
    {
      $_SESSION['lastRefresh'] = time();//This is in if, so "timer" won't reset if user refresh before 4 minutes.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your pages to random url by using following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var urls = new Array("http://www.firstURL.com/", "http://www.SecondURL.com/");

function redirect(){
    window.location = urls[Math.floor(urls.length*Math.random())];
}

setInterval("redirect()", 4000);

</script>
```

Comment: What's the point of setInterval? You are refreshing the page, so it will only be called once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can refresh the page in JS as others have suggested or you can use the meta refresh you used in your example. However, using any type of timeout (or interval) doesn't make sense, as you want to refresh the complete page.

I would handle the whole logic on the backend and just worry about one refresh at a time. If you want to refresh the pages in order, just create an array of URLs and always pick the next URL from the page you are on. If you want random page loads, just pick a random array index every page.

Again, no need for any loops or intervals. They won't live long enough on either end to be useful.

Comment: @Stave i am working of a script to update a field on mysql table i have 1,755,213 entries and i am getting time out after 15000 entries so i have to load page with $_GET and change start point of query LIMIT $id, 15000 like this and reload page ... so it dont get error ... this is wt my problem is ... its all working in back end there is nothing to do with users ... ;)